# How to write values from a list after certain whitespaces?

Tags: python-2.7

I have two lists:

`x = [0,1.2]`

`y = [1,2]`

and using following to place them in two columns with second column starting after 8 white spaces.

```
for a,b in zip(x,y):
    print "{}{:>9}".format(a,b)
```

It gives:

```
0        1
1.2        2
```

But I need:

```
0        1
1.2      2
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also specify the format for the first argument (`a`).

```
>>> x = [0,1.2]
>>> y = [1,2]
>>> for a, b in zip(x, y):
...     print "{:>8}{:>9}".format(a, b)
...
       0        1
     1.2        2
>>> for a, b in zip(x, y):
...     print "{:<8}{:>9}".format(a, b)
...
0               1
1.2             2
```